# Is there any chance of a script injection using Knockout's value binding?

Tags: html, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I think knockout handles this situation, but wanted to confirm. Is it true that if using the value binding w/ a form control like input/textarea that there is no danger of a script injection attack?

Or do you need to do something to ensure the value is encoded prior to setting it in the view model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value will be saved to the view model, as is.  It just depends how you use it.  The `text` binding will encode the content based on using `innerText`/`textContent` to set the value.  So, you are safe there.  If you were to use the `html` binding with content that was set via the `value` binding, then it would be possible to inject a script.

See the Knockout doco [About HTML encoding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html) for more info.

Comment: I guess my question is if I get a string from the server and bind it to an input control with value binding, could there be problems there if the server string wasn't html encoded.

Comment: Setting a text input's value by the 'value' binding is safe.